# How to change setting to access my SQLite database remotely

Tags: sqlite, remote-access, pos

I'm trying to set up a POS system on two pc locally
Please how do i change this setting to connect and save to the database remotely ?

> db_host   localhost
>
> db_hostaddr 127.0.0.1
>
> db_name pos
>
> db_password 123
>
> db_port 5432
>
> db_user postgres
>
> db_driver   SQLite
>
> data_dir    data
>
> data_db pos_data.sdb
>
> update_server   127.0.0.1
>
> update_user max
>
> update_pass 123

Comment: As far as I know, SQLite doesn't have any sort of network connectivity component, other than being able to store database files on file shares handled by the operating system. Do you have any sort of server component that you access this through?

Answer (score 0):

This 'config file' suggests there at least two different DBMSes involved: **PostgreSQL** and **SQLite**. Surely there is more to it. A SQLite DB fits in a standalone file (+ temporary files). The PostgreSQL instance is probably running locally, hence localhost/127.0.0.1.

There is not enough information on that POS system. Maybe it's an open source project and there is some documentation available, if it is a proprietary application, maybe there is still documentation, otherwise you have to check with the vendor. Perhaps the source code (if available) has some useful comments too...

Actually it's impossible to advise without knowing your **network setup**. It's not as easy as moving the database to another machine. You have to know the IP address or host name of the server, and there should be a firewall tuned to allow connections to the database server.

Probably, you change `db_host` and `db_hostaddr`, and test. But it's not clear what `update_server` is and what it does. Nor is it clear what each database (PostgreSQL and SQLite) contains and how the application is structured.

You need to provide a lot more information if you want help.